# Help with NiceHash 2

Tags: nicehash

I'm using NiceHash Miner v.2 for mining on my desktop PC. But since the last update I can't mine because the program says I need to update the drivers of my GTX 1070, but my GPU is uploaded to recently version and does not work. Does any one have solution, or has gone through the same?